# On Langevin equation and Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Citing from Wikipedia:

> For an Itô drift-diffusion process
> $$dX_{t}=\mu _{t}\,dt+\sigma _{t}\,dB_{t}$$
> and any twice differentiable scalar function $f(t,x)$ of two real variables $t$ and $x$, one has
> $$df(t,X_{t})=\left({\frac {\partial f}{\partial t}}+\mu _{t}{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}}+{\frac {\sigma _{t}^{2}}{2}}{\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}}\right)dt+\sigma _{t}{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}}\,dB_{t}$$

The important part to notice here is that $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ are *deterministic* functions, namely, they depend (possibly) only on $t$ but not on $B_t$ (as pointed out in the related Wiki page).

**Question**. **Is Ito's lemma applicable to the Langevin equation?**
$$
dY_t=aY_t d t + b\,d B_t, \qquad a,b\in\mathbb{R}
$$
(here $Y_t$ is the velocity process and $dB_t=\Xi_tdt$, where $\Xi_t$ is a white noise).

Apparently, it can't, for in this case $\mu_t=aY_t$ is *not* deterministic.
So either Ito's lemma *does not* require $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ to be deterministic, or something else which at this point I don't know.

Comment: Ito's lemma does not require $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ to be deterministic. There is probably another wikipedia page that mentions this well-known fact.

Comment: If you are referring to this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma, an example with deterministic drift and diffusion coefficients is discussed in the motivation section, but it is not a requirement to apply Itô's lemma in general (cf. the geometric brownian motion further below on the same page for instance).